# How to set View height/width according to another View's height/width by ratio?

Tags: android, xml, view

Say, I have 2 `View`: A and B. A's size is set to `wrap_content`, causing its size might change when content varies: text size, image size, data amounts... etc.

I want View B's height/width related to View A's, but by ratio ---- for example, **B's height is 1/3 of A's**. How can I achieve it?

As far as I know, `ConstraintLayout` should come to rescue. But I could only make it
equals by setting `constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewA"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewA"`. I tried using `Guideline` to locate the "dedicated height" -- but it seems `Guideline` is only related to **parent** (not constraint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

My solution so far is: combined `layout_constraintHeight_percent` (or `layout_constraintWidth_percent`) with a `ConstraintLayout` wrapper.

## Limit of "Percent"

I went around asking people. Some say that `layout_constraintHeight_percent` (or `layout_constraintWidth_percent`) should be used in this case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baseA"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="base A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="base B"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/baseA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/baseA" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, `layout_constraintHeight_percent` encountered the same problem as `Guideline`: they are calculated according to **parent's size**, no matter what constraint they have:

[image: constraint height percent]

Some say `layout_constrainedHeight` should set to `true`, but nothing changed:

[image: constraint height percent + constrainedHeight = true]

## Adaption: B-specified Wrapper

Above behavior gave me an idea: since `constraint percent` is only calculated by parent, then we could *modify the parent* -- by giving it a custom one.

Change above code, take view B to a new `ConstraintLayout`, migrate B into it, constraint to parent, and use `percent` again:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baseA"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="base A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/baseA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"        
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/baseA">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="base B"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: custom constraint layout + percentage]

Now it works like a charm.

## Better Approach: Inside Same Wrapper

Another solution is to put A and B inside the same `ConstraintLayout`, and set its height/width to `wrap_content`, causing its size to equal to A:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseA"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_200"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="base A"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="base B"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: constraint layout wrapper]

And I think **it's a better solution** -- because in only-B-wrapper solution, you **cannot set padding in that wrapper `ConstraintLayout`**, as `layout_constraintHeight_percent` only calculated size **inside** (it ignores padding and margin). But in above share-wrapper solution, you can set a padding without worry (as they share the same parent size).